# What does the treasure chest icon indicate on the map tooltip for Shrines?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

What does the treasure chest icon on a Shrine's tooltip (next to the Shrine's name) mean? Does it indicate that there is an unopened chest remaining, or that you have found all the chests?

[image: the icon visible on a shrine's tooltip]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From what I can find, the little treasure chest icon means you found all the chests in that Shrine.

[GameFAQs](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75061618):

> Yes it means you got them all in the shrine. Good for completionist runs

[Another GameFAQs](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75068295):

> means you got all the chests in that shrine.
>   If your other shrines don't have it, it means you missed some of the bonus chests
>
> The icon appears if there are no more chests to open in the Shrine, *and appears even if there's no chest at all*. If there wouldn't be any blue chest icon next to a Shrine with zero chests, people would spend hours and hours to look for a chest that doesn't exist and get very frustrated.

[One more GameFAQs](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75067504) that says the same thing (didn't bother to include a quote).

Comment: Does the chest shrines count in the 100% completion counter?

Comment: @Fredy31 perhaps that's better suited as a separate question, as I don't know.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/303124/does-shrine-treasures-count-toward-100

Comment: "and appears even if there's no chest at all". I'm pretty sure there isn't any shrine with no chest at all.