# Do shrine treasures count toward the completion percentage on the Sheikah Slate map?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Related to this question: [What does the treasure chest icon indicate on the map tooltip for Shrines?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/303110/what-does-the-treasure-chest-icon-indicate-on-the-map-tool-tip-for-shrines/303112?noredirect=1#comment429380_303112)

There's an indicator if all treasures in a shrine have been opened. For those who have the counter for 100% completion, does the treasure in the shrines count for 100% completion? (If you go into a completed shrine, and get the missing treasures in the shrine, does the counter in the slate move at all?)

Comment: Are you talking about the counter on the map?

Comment: Yup. Edited for precision.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This IGN page](http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/100_Percent_Completion_Checklist) states that the only thing that counts towards the completion percentage on the Sheikah Slate are:

> Dungeons cleared (and their location appearing on the map), Korok Seeds (and the icon that appears once you have claimed a seed), Shrine Discoveries, and Location Discoveries.

Basically, it appears that location discoveries are the only thing that count for that completion percentage.  The page also states that quests and the Hyrule Compendium do **not** count.

They break the percentage down into 4 categories which each yield a different amount towards the 100%:

> - Dungeon Clear (Boss Defeated) = .08% x 4 = .32%
> - Korok Seeds = .08% x 900 = 72%
> - Shrine Discovery = .08% x 120 = 9.60%
> - Location Discovery = .08% x 226(?) = 18.08%

Comment: Hoo boy, I really hope they change the weighting of that in an update...

Comment: Also, [this answer's screenshot](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/302884/163757) shows that in the official guide, these are the things tracked for this percentage.

Comment: @Riking To be fair, that's probably an accurate amount of time spent in percent on getting all 900(!) Korok seeds compared with the time spent completing the main story.